# nested object forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm a rails and ruby noob, and Im pretty sure this something completely stupid I am missing..

Trying to build a nested form, and have found many examples online, and tried and failed to reproduce the desired result.

the "seller" fields are not even displayed, and when I submit form
I get:

> unknown attribute: item

models:

```
class Dealerform < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :dealer
 has_one :seller :class_name => 'Seller'
 has_many :items, :through => :seller
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :seller, :items

end

class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :dealerform
 has_many :items :class_name => 'Item'
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :seller
end
```

view:

```
<% form_for(@dealerform) do |f| %>
<%= f.error_messages %>
 <p>
 <%= f.label :date %><br />
 <%= f.datetime_select :date %>
 </p>
      #...more fields ...

<% f.fields_for :seller do |seller| %>

<p>
 <%= seller.label :fname %><br />
 <%= seller.text_field :fname %>
</p>
      #...more fields ...

<% end %>

 <% f.fields_for :item do |item| %>
  <p>
   <%= item.label :foo %><br />
   <%= item.text_field :foo %>
  </p>
      #...more fields ...

 <% end %>

<%= f.submit 'Create' %> 
<% end %>
```

Based on suggestions..
changed the following lines:

```
<% f.fields_for :seller do |seller| %>
<% f.fields_for :item do |item| %>
```

to:

```
<% f.fields_for @seller do |seller| %>
<% f.fields_for @item do |item| %>
```

and now they show up in the form, and when trying to submit form
I get:

> unknown attribute: nil_class

when I change:

```
def new
  @dealerform = Dealerform.new
```

to:

```
def new
  @dealerform = Dealerform.new
  @dealerform.seller.build
```

I get:

> undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Hints: Please don't begin sentences with "so".  Please begin sentences with Capital Letters.  Please capitalize "I".

Comment: Reminder — if you're working in Rails 3.0.0 or 2.3.9, be sure to upgrade now, since there is a [security vulnerability](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/10/15/security-vulnerability-in-nested-attributes-code-in-ruby-on-rails-2-3-9-and-3-0-0) for `accepts_nested_attributes_for`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `fields_for` attribute wil only display resources that exist. In your controller you need to build objects for the forms to containe.

So in your controller

```
def new
    #2.times {@dealer_form.items}
    @dealer_form = DealerForm.new
    @dealer_form.seller = Seller.new
    #or @dealer_form.seller.build
end
```

Comment: made this change and now get:  undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass

Comment: It just means that you are building something that doesn't exist.

Comment: check your associations. You have too many for me to go over each and if I did I'm not sure you declared all of them correctly. Just make sure sellers is actually a has_many and so on... :)

Comment: @Sam: this is the result I'd expect from `@dealer_form.seller.build`. If there is no seller defined yet, `@dealer_form.seller` will return `nil`, right? Or is there some Ruby duck typing there that I haven't dealt with before?

Comment: I don't really know. Its sounds like you got more than a simple thing setup. Start with a really simple association and then move from there. As for the nil error your getting it just means that your associations are wrong.

Comment: I went back and started over following the example here:  http://github.com/mauricioszabo/Nested-Forms-example  and was able to get it working.. thanks!

Comment: np. Sometimes things can just get too complicated and it's best to get a simple version running first :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your dealerform model has_many items but your fields_for is submitting a singular item, so when it tries to initialize your dealerform in the create action it's trying to assign dealerform.item but there's no such method. If a dealerform has many items you may want to check out this example http://media.pragprog.com/titles/fr_arr/multiple_models_one_form.pdf for how to manage the has_many in a single form.

Answer (score 0):

As Sam indicated, you ned to have an actual object, whether new or existing:

`f.fields_for @seller`

You can get `@seller` in several different ways,  using `build` to create a new one, or if you are editing an existing record, use `@dealerform.seller`.

In the case of items, you may need to loop over several, depending on how many form you want to display. Check out http://www.railscasts.com for some screencasts on this.